# In Azure DevOps is it better to use one variable group or multiple to split environmental variables?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When creating variable groups for one thing spanning across multiple environments, is it better to use a single variable group or multiple, and why?

Option 1: One variable group per environment with identically named variables
Variable Group Animals Dev:

- VariableA = "Dog"
- VariableB = "Cat"

Variable Group Animals Prod:

- VariableA = "Chicken"
- VariableB = "Dolphin"

Option 2: One variable group for all environments with variables named to match the environment
Variable Group Animals:

- VariableA.Dev = "Dog"
- VariableB.Dev = "Cat"
- VariableA.Prod = "Chicken"
- VariableB.Prod = "Dolphin"

Option 1 means more variable groups but means all variables across environments share the same name and also allows you to limit the available variables to a smaller scope in your pipeline.
Option 2 means all variable are contained in the one group which is potentially cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use **Option 1.**

This allows you to *reuse* pipeline templates in your different stages. All you have to do is to load the desired variable group within your stage.job.

Example:

```
# azure-pipeline.yml
stages:
- stage: DEV
  variables:
  - group: DEV
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - script: echo $(VariableA)
- stage: PROD
  variables:
  - group: PROD
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - script: echo $(VariableA)
```

Comment: just be aware that if you load both groups in the same scope then because the variables have the same name, only one of the values (e.g. either `DEV group VariableA` or `PROD group VariableA` will be assigned as `VariableA`) will be used and there will be no warning message

Answer (score 2):

Variable group are designed to have an easy way to share variables across pipelines, right? So to have all done easily better is to keep env variables in separate variable groups because in that way you can keep the same names in all stages/pipelines (I don't know how you organize your pipelines). However, if you go with this:

Dev:

```
VariableA = "Dog"
VariableB = "Cat"
```

Variable Group Animals Prod:

```
VariableA = "Chicken"
VariableB = "Dolphin"
```

you will get dev and prod working without changing used names.

It is like Azure KeyVault, better is to have one per env, than one for all envs.